# Where can I download network drivers for my BCM 4313?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, broadcom

I'm running 10.04 Desktop Edition on my netbook, but it hasn't automatically installed my network drivers for my Broadcom device. I'd like to find a package on the internet for it, so I can transfer it to my netbook with a USB pen drive. I don't care if the drivers are proprietary. Here is the output of lspci.

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Device 9804
00:01.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Wrestler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6250/6310]
00:11.0 SATA controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Wifi Docs Driver BCM 43xx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) from the Community Wiki. Looks like your card requires the STA driver. If you have Internet access, make sure the restricted repository (multiverse) is enabled, that repositories are updated

> sudo apt-get update

then install `bcmwl-kernel-source`

> sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Now you should see the driver available in the Additional Drivers (it's in *System Settings*). Install it. Reboot or run the following commands:

> sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
>
> sudo modprobe wl

If you don't have Internet access, you can install `bcmwl-kernel-source` either by adding the Live CD as a repository or by finding the package on the Ubuntu install media (CD or pendrive) under **../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl**. You'll also need the dependencies, those are `dkms`, `patch` and `fakeroot`. You can find them in **../pool/main/d/dkms**, **../pool/main/p/patch**, **../pool/main/f/fakeroot** respectively. Install those before you install `bcmwl-kernel-source`.